# Please help : How to express "macro economy changes in a few percentage points can impact people a lot "

Tags: usage

Question : how to correctly say "macro economy changes in a few percentage points can impact people a lot "

I want to express that macro economy growth changes every year(usually in two continuous years the changes are samll like 1-3%), but this small changes in number can have big impacts on people's life. There are a few questions I am not sure:

1. is this part  "macro eonomy changes in a few percentage points" OK? I feel there might be a much simple way to express this;
2. is the usage "impact people" correct? what's the usual way to say this?

Comment: It's macro **economic** changes, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*in* a few percentage points" is not correct. You may use:

> *of* a few percentage points

or

> *in the range of* a few percentage points

or you can also drop the mentioning of percentages and use expressions like *relatively small*, *seemingly insignificant* or similar. If i understand you correctly you want to stress the seemingly contradictory nature of "small change - big influence" rather than some exact percentage points. Therefore you could forego mentioning these percentages altogether.

*impact people* is generally OK, although I would replace "people" with "(the) population". You don't talk about singular identifiable persons here, but about - rather anonymous - *citizens of a nation* or the like.

Comment: Got it, Bakunin. I really appreicate your help, my friend!!!